# JQuery Multiple attributes

Tags: jquery, if-statement, attr

So I have something that looks like this:

```
<src id="Point_1" href="pin_icon_red_attack.png">
```

Why doesn't this JQuery work?:

```
if( $('img[id*="Point_"][src="pin_icon_red_attack.png"]')   ) {
// do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This selector looks for an image with an href of `pin_icon_red_attack.png` that's inside an image with an id that contains `Point_`.

Also, in HTML, the tag is `<img>`, not `<image>`, and it's `src=` not `href=`.

```
<img id="Point_1" src="pin_icon_red_attack.png" />
```

It should be:

```
$('img[id*="Point_"][src="pin_icon_red_attack.png"]')
```

Also, in the if statement you need to add `.length`, because when jQuery finds nothing, it returns a blank array (which JavaScript evaluates to `true`).

```
if($('img[id*="Point_"][src="pin_icon_red_attack.png"]').length){
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/usjz6/3/

NOTE: If the ID always starts with `Point_` you can use `[id^="Point_"]` (starts with) instead of `[id*="Point_"]`.

Comment: Just another question, if you don't mind.. so the rendered browser code looks like this:  http://jsfiddle.net/bakQj/1/  See it's from OpenLayers, I understand what you mean using img and src.  What happens in this case?

Comment: Chrome renders that as an `img` tag.  `<image>` tags are not valid in HTML like that.  OpenLayers could use an `<svg>` or other tag where having `<image>` is valid.